# Prove a theorem on convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$  be two sequences with $a_n >0 $ and $b_n>0$ for all $n\ge N$ and let $c_n=b_n-b_{n+1}a_{n+1}/a_n$. Prove that:

If there is a possitive constant $r$ such that $c_n \ge r \gt 0$ for all $n\ge N$,then $\sum a_n$ converges.

I tried :
$a_nb_n\gt a_{n+1}b_
{n+1}$. So, the sequence $a_nb_n$ is decreasing. Then for $n\ge N$,
$a_nb_n\le a_Nb_N$, 
so $a_n\le a_Nb_N/b_n\lt a_Nb_N/r$, because $a_nb_n\gt a_nr$.
Each term of the sequence $a_n$ is smaller than the constant $a_Nb_N/r$ for $n\ge N$, but I dont know if this implies that the partial sums of $a_n$ are bounded and the series converges.

Comment: This is known as Kummer test see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test .  The interesting thing is that with Kummer test you can make a lot of new tests. In fact, Kummer test is the factory of producing a new test for convergence of series.

Comment: In fact 1867, Genocchi was the first person who highlighted this Kummer test see his old paper written in French http://www.numdam.org/article/NAM_1867_2_6__261_0.pdf

Comment: See also this well written Bachelor thesis http://oldwww.dcs.fmph.uniba.sk/bakalarky/obhajene/getfile.php/new.pdf?id=90&fid=228&type=application%2Fpdf

Comment: Bertrand’s Test, Raabe test, d’Alembert’s Ratio Test, and Gauss test can be produced by the Kummer test

Comment: We can extend the Kummer test by the m th Ratio Test (see p.10) https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_12/papers/kyle.pdf  it can be a good bachelor project i.e instead $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ we use $\frac{a_{mn+k−1}}{a_n}$ or instead $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ we write $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ in Kummer test . Good luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that the condition can be written as

$$ c_n a_n = b_n a_n - b_{n+1}a_{n+1} $$

and hence

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{c_n}{r} a_n = \frac{b_{1}a_{1} - b_{N+1}a_{N+1}}{r} \leq \frac{b_{1}a_{1}}{r}. $$

So the partial sum of $(a_n)$ is monotone increasing and bounded above, hence converges.